# How do I create a data base in MySQL and add a user?

Tags: mysql, php

To start working with MySQL from PHP I need to connect to the MySQL server using "mysql_connect". Doing so, I need to specify user-name and password. But for that I need first to create a user with a password. How can I do it?

After I connect to the MySQL server I need to select a data base. But for that the DB should exist. How do I create a DB? Can I do it from PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following with the mysql command line client

MYSQL CREATE DB COMMAND - `CREATE DATABASE mydbname`

MYSQL CREATE USER COMMAND - `CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'`;

MYSQL ASSIGN USER PRIVILEGES COMMAND - `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydbname TO 'myuser'@'localhost';`

your php connect script would be something like this

```
$dbuser = "myuser";
$dbpass = "mypassword";
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = "mydbname";

$db = mysql_connect ($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db ($dbname,$db);
```

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
Since you don't have MySQL installed, here are instructions for installing PHP, Apache and MySQL. [howtoforge.com](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies)

---

You'll need a user setup before you create the DB.  This will probably have to be done through mysql itself or through your ISPs control panel

The MySQL command syntax for adding a user is as follows:

```
CREATE USER user [IDENTIFIED BY [PASSWORD] 'password']
    [, user [IDENTIFIED BY [PASSWORD] 'password']] ...
```

You can then use the GRANT command to allow particular access.  Here's the syntax:

```
GRANT
    priv_type [(column_list)]
      [, priv_type [(column_list)]] ...
    ON [object_type] priv_level
    TO user [IDENTIFIED BY [PASSWORD] 'password']
        [, user [IDENTIFIED BY [PASSWORD] 'password']] ...
    [REQUIRE {NONE | ssl_option [[AND] ssl_option] ...}]
    [WITH with_option ...]

object_type:
    TABLE
  | FUNCTION
  | PROCEDURE

priv_level:
    *
  | *.*
  | db_name.*
  | db_name.tbl_name
  | tbl_name
  | db_name.routine_name

ssl_option:
    SSL
  | X509
  | CIPHER 'cipher'
  | ISSUER 'issuer'
  | SUBJECT 'subject'

with_option:
    GRANT OPTION
  | MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR count
  | MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR count
  | MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR count
  | MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS count
```

Here's the method for using mysql_connect to connect to a database: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)
Here's the method for creating a db with php: [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-create-db.php)

Comment: The question is how to create a user, not how to connect to the server.

Comment: I did it before through control panel (when I used commercial web server). But now I am working on my computer and I have no control panel. So, I think I need to do it via command line in MySQL. And the question is how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

There's a command to set the root user's password, but I don't remember what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the MySQL server yet?  If not try going here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing.html

If you have then you can skip to this section:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/unix-post-installation.html

Comment: When I type mysql in the command line (in Ubuntu) I get: The program 'mysql' is currently not installed. It is also written: You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.0. I think it will be the easiest way if I just type "sudo apt-get install ...". Will it work this way?

Comment: That will install the client you can use to access mysql - which you will need - but you will also need to install the actual server itself.  Your best bet is to follow the (HowToForge) tutorial in Griffo's post (http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies) to make sure that all the working parts are there.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of good tool providing you with the details about how to do it from the command line.  Another method you might want to consider is setting up [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or the [Mysql GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html).  These interfaces will give you an easier starting point.